# "Picky eaters" en français

Tags: vocabulaire, adjectifs

Comment traduire "picky eaters" en français? 
"Picky" désigne des personnes difficiles à satisfaire.
Je cherche une expression qui donne la signification exacte de "picky eaters".

Answer (score 9):

On peut dire de quelqu’un qui n’aime pas beaucoup de choses qui se mangent qu’il est « difficile ». Dans le [Trésor de langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/difficile), on trouve l’acception au paragraphe B.

Comment: http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=picky+eaters propose aussi **capricieux** selon les contextes

Comment: @ Edouard, Est ce que je peux dire "les mangeurs difficiles"

Comment: @houneida Pas vraiment, *mangeur* n'est pas idiomatique ici et s'emploie dans essentiellement dans des expressions toutes faites ("gros mangeur", "mangeur d'homme", etc.) `Les personnes difficiles` suffit et sera compris grâce au contexte, éventuellement en rajoutant `sur le plan de la nourriture` si on veut être hyper explicite.

Comment: @guillaume31, Merci pour votre réponse

Answer (score 3):

Je les appellerais des « fines bouches ».

Answer (score 2):

It’s probably most often used in reference to an adult with super, perhaps unreasonably high standards, but someone who is “**exigeant** (sur la nourriture/bouffe)" is nevertheless a picky eater.

Comment: un bouffeur exigeant [c'est une blague]......difficile à plaire=picky. Isn't it funny that for a culture so obsessed with food, their is no good word for eater other than some metaphor or other with bouche.

Comment: Correx: there is, not their is. :)

Answer (score -1):

*Picky* (about anything, not just food): *pointilleux*.

Comment: Pointilleux means "obsessed with details", it doesn't work here.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: See [here](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/pointilleux) or [beyond](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=pointilleux+traduction). It means *picky*, as I said.  (And as you apparently agree, even with your definition of *picky*.) I was clear in my answer that *picky* and *pointilleux* can be applied to anything. This question is about *picky eater*.

Comment: ...Is that a joke? Even the links you provide contradict what you say. And you don't point at a translation dictionary to find the meaning of a word, you use a regular dictionary. Let me quote CNRTL: [Qui a une propension à disputer sur des points de détail, qui ne laisse passer aucune chose même peu importante.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pointilleux) This doesn't fit at all with "picky eater". POicky can mean pointilleux in some contexts, but not all of them.

Comment: Nope, not a joke. I maintain my answer. You are free to disagree. A *picky eater* **picks at** his/her food, paying great **attention to detail**, and choosing only these bits and not those bits to eat. *Picky eater* is not *choosy eater* (which can refer to picking at the food or just choosing among menu suggestions). Whether the great attention to detail of a *picky eater* fits your personal definition of "**obsessed** with details" is up to you to decide.